# Project subdocument elements when element name not known in Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a JSON file that was imported into Mongo:

```
{
  "people": {
      "Employee1234": {
          "salary": 10000,
          "dept": "accounting"
       },
       "Employee1235": {
           "salary": 40000,
           "dept": "CEO"
       },
       ...
  }
}
```

I want to be able to find all of the unique salaries and departments of the people.

This is tricky because the `people` aren't in a `[]` with their ID as a field, but rather the elements are their EID.  I'm trying to do the equivalent of `find({},{people.*.dept})`, but you can't do a `*` wildcard.  How can I query this *(Given that this is the schema of the existing documents)* ?

Answer (score 1):

That would be quite impossible with just a MongoDB query with the current schema where you have dynamic keys. However, I would suggest you change the schema such that the keys become values and store them in an embedded document. Something like this schema would be very easy to query:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Employee1234",
            "salary": 10000,
            "dept": "accounting"
        },
            "name": "Employee1235",
            "salary": 40000,
            "dept": "CEO"
        }       
    ]
}
```

Converting the current schema to the one above would use some native JavaScript:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var people = [],
        keys = Object.keys(doc.people);
        obj = {};

    keys.forEach(function(key){
        obj = doc.people[key];
        obj.name = key
        people.push(obj);
    });

    doc.people = people;
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

After changing the schema, you would now be able to query using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. The aggregation pipeline which would find all of the unique salaries and departments of the people is as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$people"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "salary": "$people.salary",
                "department": "$people.dept"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "count": 1 }
    }
]);
```

For the above sample document, the output would be:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "salary" : 40000,
                "department" : "CEO"
            },
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "salary" : 10000,
                "department" : "accounting"
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Ugh.  I was afraid that was the answer.  These documents are being generated constantly, so I'd have to come up with the method for transforming them before importing them into the db.  Also, it'd be nice to keep the documents in their native format.  And just to make things even more fun, this odd "key element" format happens at multiple layers in the document.  Sigh